# How to use CAML query with rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

I am trying to get list data with an `id` from my SharePoint online through `REST`. I have my `ajax` call like below.

```
getFunction:function(id){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
$.ajax({
 async: true,
 method: 'POST',
 url:myUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ABExtensionStore')/RenderListDataAsStream",
 headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: resolve
 });
});
}
```

As i was using the `RenderListDataAsStream` it is giving entire list data. But I need only few columns with an `id`. So can anyone suggest how to query those list items. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link. This will guide you to use caml query with REST API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959179/sharepoint-rest-api-filter-empty-lookup-field/40972290#40972290

Comment: Glad for your reply. But it doest give values and will throw error. As I mentioned above in my question I used "RenderListDataAsStream". It doesnt work well with it.
you can go through answer below I posted which got me answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the result but there is no documentation or articles found on these properties used

> this is what i found. But I did not found what is `RenderOptions` and what value should be given.
>   If anyone know can share the answer.

```
   getFunction:function(id) {


      <---here we can write our CAML Query
    var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value  Type='Counter'>"+id+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields></View>";

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            method: 'POST',
            url:myUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ABExtensionStore')/RenderListDataAsStream",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                parameters:{
                    RenderOptions:2, <-- based on this render options data will be produced
                    ViewXml:caml  <---here i gave a caml Query
                }
            }),

            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: resolve
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id of the item dynamically to the rest url and get only those items.

```
getFunction:function(id){
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
$.ajax({
 async: true,
 method: 'POST',
 url:myUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ABExtensionStore')/items(" + id + ")",
 headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        resolve(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        reject(data);
    }
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: glad for your reply.. but once go through my question again. I wanted to use that "RenderListDataAsStream" . It doesn't support giving Id dynamically.By the way I got the solution. You can go through here [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/249522/78182)